# How to call controller within another conroller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, controller

I am using cakephp v2.6 to develop a web app.

Is it possible to call a controller within another controller in CAKEPHP.

Is it correct way for doing the same

In SecondController.php

```
App::uses('FirstController','Controller');

class SecondController extends AppController
{
$firstcontrollerobject=$this->FirstController;
}
```

Thanqs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is `Yes`, but you shouldn't.

You should use either a component or a model. Or put your action in `AppController` if you want it to be used by other controllers.

```
App::uses('FirstController','Controller');

class SecondController extends AppController
{
    public function test() {
        $FirstController = new FirstController();
        $Firstcontroller->action();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Put PHP code in the Component, if you want to share between several controllers**

> Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers. CakePHP comes with a fantastic set of core components you can use to aid in various common tasks. You can also create your own components. If you find yourself wanting to copy and paste things between controllers, you should consider creating your own component to contain the functionality. Creating components keeps controller code clean and allows you to reuse code between projects.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html